# SQLite can't set sqlite3_temp_directory with WinRT

Tags: c++, sqlite, windows-runtime

I'm getting started with SQLite in my WinRT C++ application and I'm having a few problems.

First, on http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/temp_directory.html it says that you have to set up the sqlite_temp_directory with the following code:

```
LPCWSTR zTempPath = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->TemporaryFolder->Path->Data();      

char zTempPathBuf[MAX_PATH + 1];        

memset(zTempPathBuf, 0, sizeof(zTempPathBuf));      

WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, zTempPath, -1, zTempPathBuf, sizeof(zTempPathBuf), NULL, NULL); 

sqlite3_temp_directory = zTempPathBuf;
```

When I try to run this code, the last line causes a memory access violation.

Comment: I see the same when building a Windows Store app (using SQLite 3.13.0). The symbol `sqlite3_temp_directory` properly gets imported through the import LIB. However, when resolved at runtime, it points at a location inside my EXE module, not the sqlite3.dll. This happens for Debug/Release, x86, and x64. (P.S.: I am using `sqlite3_mprintf` to obtain a pointer to memory with the appropriate lifetime; the code in the question doesn't, but it seems this is not the issue).